# Need Help with Symmetrize

Tags: armature, bones

I am a newbie Blender, i have a problem with symmetrize, tried to Name it Left and Right and Symmetrize -X to X axis but the symmetrize generated on the same side, can anyone able to solve my problems? tried solution on youtube still generate the bones on the sameside. Thanks[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Symmetrize will happen on the X axis, not Y axis, so, before symmetrizing, select your bones in *Edit* mode and rotate them 90° on the Z axis

Comment: hello thanks for answering, but can you take a look again at the picture? i just updated the picture with the current problem with the project i've been  working on related to the armature symmetrization. need your help please,  thankss

Comment: Have you tried to rotate your bones 90° on Z before symmetrizing? If it still doesn't work please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: hi thanks for answering again, it worked thanks a lot.